# Fail2ban and custom log

Tags: logging, phpbb

In phpbb I created a script that results in a customlog looks like this:

[Mon Nov 14 15:35:52 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]  ip=127.0.0.1 user=bebe password=112233 error=wrong password , referer: http://aaa.com

[Mon Nov 14 15:48:25 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]  ip=127.0.0.1 user=bobo password=445566 error=wrong password , referer: http://aaa.com

[Mon Nov 14 15:57:04 2011] [error] [client 1237.0.0.1] ip=127.0.0.1 user=bubu password=778899 error=wrong password , referer: http://aaa.com

How should be a filter in fail2ban to block five unsuccessful attempts to login ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

failregex = [[]client []] .* error=wrong password